# Assertion in Java for AP C.S. homework

Tags: java, assertion

I'm creating a simple bank account class, "BankAccount". The goal is to enhance the class to make sure that desired values are reached. For example, when constructing a new object of the class the constructor requires that the initial balance is greater than $0. It asks you to use assertion

```
public class BankAccount 
{

priavte int balance;

public BankAccount(int initialBalance)
{
    assert (initialBalance > 0);
    balance = initialBalance; 
}
}
```

Is this the proper way to use assertion? And what exactly will the assert statement do if InitialBalance < 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way to use assertions. In fact, Oracle has [made clear](https://web.archive.org/web/20111207043916/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) that assertions should not check method parameters, and more importantly, one should never assert the result of a function call with a side effect (since there are no guarantees it will actually be executed).

They are designed to be used to check invariants (for example, a list class might include some elements and an `int length`, and that length must be equal to the number of elements). Another example of the correct use:

```
public Foo acquireFoo(int id) {
  Foo result = null;
  if (id > 50) {
    result = fooService.read(id);
  } else {
    result = new Foo(id);
  }
  assert result != null;

  return result;
}
```

If the Java application is running with `-ea` on the command-line, then assertions will be enabled. When the application reaches `assert (initialBalance > 0);`, if initialBalance is less than 0 **and** assertions are enabled, a [`java.lang.AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) will be thrown. If `-ea` is not passed, then the assertion error will not be thrown.

It would be wiser to throw a [`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) as follows:

```
public BankAccount(int initialBalance)
{
    if (initialBalance < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The initial balance may not be negative.");
    }
    balance = initialBalance; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use an existing framework for tests that has a lot of common assertions in it.**